# MVC and Multi-Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller

I have a (Model) class `classModel` which implements `Runnable`.

My controller `Manager` (which is a Singleton) will create 2 threads for 2 objects 'classModel'.

First question : Is this the work of the controller to do this ? Or should I create another class which will create threads and start them ?

Then, in my `classModel.run()` I'll send Strings (every loop) to my `Manager` which share it (with a `List<String>`) to show it in the view.

How am I supposed to do that ? My view needs to implement `Runnable` and check every loop if something is shared in the controller ? Or another way ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Model just holds data. Controller always delegates its works.

Yes, you need to create in between class that take command from controller and call it Service.

Comment: Model just holds data when you adopt the *anemic domain model*.